# Polyglot note-keeping?

Tags: latex

I sometimes give roughly the same course in different languages, and update my TeX notes (if any) each time. Keeping all sets of notes current is a pain (and doesn´t always get done). Does anybody know of a system for keeping and updating the same math document in different languages? The text would vary and the math would be the same, except for eventual changes in order due to differences in sentence structure.

Comment: Obviously, you need to keep them all in Esperanto. Voted to close as off-topic.

Comment: Perhaps the question is more suited for tex.stackexchange.com, no?

Comment: Interestingly, Harald actually speaks Esperanto, so your suggestion, while tongue in cheek, may be feasible.

Answer (score 1):

First, a parable: A man comes to a doctor and says: Doctor, it hurts when I do THAT. The doctor replies: Well, then don't do THAT!

In this case, why don't you give the lectures in the appropriate language, but keep the notes in, say, English? Unless you give many talks in elementary schools in Albania, I am sure your listeners know how to read English.

Comment: There are plenty of serious mathematics students whose command of English is at the same level as your average English-speaking mathematics student´s command of French. Notes in English are a suboptimal possibility. Also, now that I think of it, I was once contacted by an Albanian secondary school teacher who wanted to know my opinion about teaching calculus through non-standard analysis. He wrote to me in Esperanto, obviously. 